# Approximate comparison of 2 Ruby DateTimes

Tags: ruby

I have 2 `DateTime`s and I want to check if they're roughly 24 hours apart, plus or minus a small amount, say 5 minutes. Is there a built in way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not, but it is easy enough:

```
(-5 * 60 .. 5 * 60).include?((t2 - t1).abs - 24 * 3600)
```

"is the absolute difference between the two dates, when you subtract a full day, within plus or minus five minutes?"

Comment: Obligatory "This should go in a function". This one-liner is cute but it takes a minute to decipher. If it's wrapped in a function called `def approximately_one_day` then it suddenly becomes a lot clearer.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It should be refactored according to the level needed by the application. Is it always one day? Is the margin always the same? I showed the calculation, and leave the final expression to OP to decide, in order to fit with their project.

Comment: Right, my comment was not a criticism of this answer (I realize it could be read that way now) but was intended as a note to the OP to not blindly copy-paste this without thinking out how it fits in.

Comment: Though [Range#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) is here equivalent to [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) (because the endpoints of the range are numeric), perhaps `cover?` would be a better choice, should a reader think `include?` is stepping through each element of the range.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1: Works for both `DateTime` and `Time`. Converts everything to seconds.

```rb
def time_apart_within_drift?(t1, t2, diff: 24*60*60, drift: 5*60)
  (t1.to_i - t2.to_i).abs <= diff + drift
end
```

As per the [Ruby Style Guide](https://rubystyle.guide/#no-datetime), you should almost always use `Time` instead of `DateTime`. A `Time` object can still include the date, and it will make your calculations much cleaner.

This is because subtracting two `DateTime` objects gives you the difference in days as a `Rational` object, whereas subtracting two `Time` objects gives you the difference in seconds as a `Float`.

This allows you to write your function like so:

```rb
def time_apart_within_drift?(t1, t2, diff: 24*60*60, drift: 5*60)
  (t1 - t2).abs <= diff + drift
end

# true
time_apart_within_drift?(Time.new(2020,3,5), Time.new(2020,3,4))

# true
time_apart_within_drift?(Time.new(2020,3,5), Time.new(2020,3,3,23,57))

# false
time_apart_within_drift?(Time.new(2020,3,5), Time.new(2020,3,3,23,47))
```

If using `Time` as well as `rails` and/or `activesupport`, the args can be made more readable using `Duration` objects:

```rb
def time_apart_within_drift?(t1, t2, diff: 24.hours, drift: 5.minutes)
  (t1 - t2).abs <= diff + drift
end
```